# Find angle between diagonal of a quadrilateral knowing two sides are equal.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In the following problem, I am trying to find angle $x$:

[image]

All the ugly drawn parts are of course my attempts to solve the problem from the data given. I have tried finding similar triangles or anything that can help, to no avail. I seem to have practically every angle, but I'm unable to make progress. The only other idea I've come up with from here is to make a circle with center $C$ in order to apply some circle theorems, but that also led nowhere. Please help me.

Comment: It was given. It was easy to reason the angles knowing BCD is isosceles, you can just apply opposite angle theorem a bunch of times. Haven't actually handwritten the problem,  I was waiting till I knew the approach I should follow, but got stuck.

Comment: Hmm... this is a variant of [Adventitious angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles#Generalization) ( also know as 
*World's Hardest Easy Geometry Problem*). No idea how to prove it but $x$  should be $30^\circ$ (I once wrote a function to compute this sort of angle numerically using trigonometry). good luck ;-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting!  Let $m=BC=CD$, the law of sines gives

$\dfrac{m}{\sin x}= \dfrac{AC}{\sin(x+42)}$ and $\dfrac{m}{\sin 18}= \dfrac{AC}{\sin 36}$

From which we get  $\sin(x+42) = 2\cos 18 \cdot\sin x$.

By observation, the answer is $x=30$.

Comment: How do you know that $\angle ABC$ is $x+42$? Shouldn't it be $138-x$? (I think you assumed that, as you are claiming the angle opposite to $AC$ is $x+42$ right?). I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, just kind of confused. Maybe I'm remembering the law of sines wrong.

Comment: $\angle ABC = 180-(x+42$) and $\sin(180-\theta)=\sin \theta$

Comment: Oh, thank you!!!

Comment: Wait, I have one last question. Did you solve the final equation with a calculator, or are there any tricks to find $x$?

Comment: I observed that $\sin 72 = \cos 18$ and that $\sin 30 = \dfrac{1}{2}$.  However I'm guessing that there is some trig way of solving this.

Answer (score 2):

Let point $E$ be on $AD$ such that $CE=CD$.

Now, observe that, through angle chasing , $\triangle BCE$ is equilateral. Also, $\angle ACE=18^{\circ}=\angle CAE$ and thus $CE=EA$.

$CE=BE=EA$ and therefore points $B$, $C$ and $A$ all lie on the circle with centre $E$ and radius $CE$.

Hence, $\angle x=\frac {1}{2}\angle BEC=\boxed{30^{\circ}}$